# How to find out which hosting company someone is hosting at?

Tags: web-hosting

You can [whois](http://www.networksolutions.com/whois/index.jsp) a domain to see who the domain is registered with.

Is there anyway you can find out which *company* a individual is hosting with?  (i.e. Rackspace, Godaddy, etc.)

Answer (score 8):

The best you could do is ping / nslookup it to get the IP; and lookup who the IP belongs to. Given superuser.com as an example:

> PING superuser.com (64.34.119.12): 56 data bytes
>   64 bytes from 64.34.119.12: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=50.067 ms

Then doing a WHOIS on the IP Address:

```
VCSJONESMBP:~ kjones$ whois "n 64.34.119.12"
#
# The following results may also be obtained via:
# http://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=64.34.119.12?showDetails=true&showARIN=false&ext=netref2
#

NetRange:       64.34.0.0 - 64.34.255.255
CIDR:           64.34.0.0/16
OriginAS:
NetName:        PEER1-BLK-08
NetHandle:      NET-64-34-0-0-1
Parent:         NET-64-0-0-0-0
NetType:        Direct Allocation
Comment:        For abuse issues please e-mail abuse@peer1.net. All
Comment:        other inquiries can be directed to support@peer1.net. Our 24 x 7 NOC is
Comment:        available at 866-484-2588
RegDate:        2004-07-15
Updated:        2006-11-06
Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-64-34-0-0-1

OrgName:        Peer 1 Network Inc.
OrgId:          PER1
Address:        75 Broad Street
Address:        2nd Floor
City:           New York
StateProv:      NY
PostalCode:     10004
Country:        US
RegDate:
Updated:        2010-07-22
Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/org/PER1

OrgAbuseHandle: NSA-ARIN
OrgAbuseName:   Peer 1 Network AUP Enforcement
OrgAbusePhone:  +1-604-484-2588
OrgAbuseEmail:  abuse@peer1.net
OrgAbuseRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/NSA-ARIN

OrgTechHandle: ZP55-ARIN
OrgTechName:   PEER 1 Network Inc
OrgTechPhone:  +1-604-683-7747
OrgTechEmail:  net-admin@peer1.net
OrgTechRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ZP55-ARIN

RNOCHandle: ZP55-ARIN
RNOCName:   PEER 1 Network Inc
RNOCPhone:  +1-604-683-7747
RNOCEmail:  net-admin@peer1.net
RNOCRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ZP55-ARIN

#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
#
```

And indeed, superuser.com is hosted on Peer1 networks (see the bolded text).

This approach however is flawed though. If they used a load balancing service like Elastic Load Balancing; you would probably get the IP address of the load balancer, not the actual host. The same can be said for a proxy server.

Answer (score 2):

I find http://www.robtex.com useful for that kind of information.  Enter the domain name, click **Lucky**, go to the **Records** tab and check the **AS** column to see who runs the servers involved.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.whoishostingthis.com/ does a decent job of determining this, though the potential flaws @vcsjones brings up still apply.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you can do an IP lookup and this will tell you which range the IP address belongs to, often telling you which firm they're hosting with. For instance:

http://www.ip2location.com/demo?ipAddress=31.222.138.61

Shows that my company uses RackSpace.

Answer (score 1):

You can infer much by just looking at the domain's DNS records:

```
C:\>nslookup www.example.org
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.example.org
Address:  123.45.67.89

C:\>nslookup -type=ptr 123.45.67.89
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
89.67.45.123.in-addr.arpa     name = member9876.members.hostingcompany.com
```

First, use [nslookup](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200525) to find the site's IP address. Then, use the IP address to get any `PTR` records (reverse DNS.) Often, one (or the only) PTR record will show the hosting company's domain name (in the above example, we see that `www.example.org` is another name for `member9876.members.hostingcompany.com`.)